# In XML Schema complex type, how does restriction influence set of allowed attributes?

Tags: xml, xsd

So with XML Schema restriction you can derive a new complex type which has a subset of elements of a parent type. For example, if I have this base type:

```
<complexType name="baseType">
  <complexContent>
    <restriction base="anyType">
      <attribute name="number" type="decimal"/>
      <attribute name="quantity" type="positiveInteger"/>
      <sequence>
        <element name="first" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="string"/>
        <element name="second" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="string"/>
      </sequence>
    </restriction>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

And create the following new type:

```
<complexType name="newType">
  <complexContent>
    <restriction base="anyType">
      <attribute name="number" type="decimal"/>
      <sequence>
        <element name="first" type="string"/>
      </sequence>
    </restriction>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

My question is which attributes and elements are allowed for new type? Only `number` and `first`? What are occurs limits on the `first` element? Default (`minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"`) or from the parent (`minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"`)?

And if I have additional type:

```
<complexType name="newType2">
  <complexContent>
    <restriction base="anyType">
      <sequence>
        <element name="first" type="string"/>
      </sequence>
    </restriction>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Which attributes are allowed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a restriction you must include all the elements and attributes, from the set declared in the base type, that you wish to allow in the new type. The element declarations in the restriction will override the previous ones.

Your schema is almost correct. Within a `complexType` element, a `sequence` must appear before an `attribute` declaration. If you have this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="tns" xmlns:tns="tns">

    <complexType name="baseType">
        <complexContent>
            <restriction base="anyType">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="first" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="string"/>
                    <element name="second" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
                <attribute name="number" type="decimal"/>
                <attribute name="quantity" type="positiveInteger"/>
            </restriction>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="newType">
        <complexContent>
            <restriction base="tns:baseType"> <!-- restriction of baseType -->
                <sequence>
                    <element name="first" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
                <!-- attribute declarations are not necessary, since they allow the same types -->
            </restriction>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>

    <element name="root">
        <complexType>
            <choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <element name="base" type="tns:baseType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="new"  type="tns:newType" minOccurs="0"/>
            </choice>
        </complexType>
    </element>

</schema>
```

It will validate the two first `<base>` elements, but will fail validation in the two `<new>` elements for the reasons explained in the comments:

```
<base number="123.5" quantity="3"> <!-- will validate -->
    <first></first>
    <second></second>
</base>

<base> <!-- will validate: min occurs for <first> and <second> is zero OK --> 
</base>

<new number="123.5"> <!-- will fail validation: min occurs of <first> is one -->
</new>

<new number="123.5" quantity="3"> <!-- will validate: quantity attribute is inherited -->
    <first></first>
    <second></second> <!-- will fail validation: no <second> element allowed -->
</new>
```

The element and attribute declarations in the derived type must be equal or more *restrictive*: you can't have in the derived type:

```
<element name="first" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="string"/>
```

because in the base type there is no explicit `maxOccurs` so the value is 1, and `unbounded` wouldn't be a restriction. Also if you declare atributes as `decimal`, for example, in the base type, you can declare it again as `integer` to restrict it more, but you could not declare an attribute which originally was `integer` as `decimal` since that wouldn't be a *restriction*.

Comment: Aren't attributes still inherited? In [primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ipo.xml) it is written: " However, attribute declarations do not need to be repeated in the derived type definition; in this example, RestrictedPurchaseOrderType will inherit the orderDate attribute declaration from PurchaseOrderType. " I understood that this means attributes are still inherited if none is listed? Or is this not so?

Comment: You are correct. There is a typo in the answer as the `newType` is not actually being derived from the `baseType` but from `anyType`. I will fix it.

Comment: In that case the attribute declarations are not necessary, unless you wish to *restrict* an attribute type (e.g.: make `number` require an `integer` instead of any `decimal`.)

Comment: Note that I needed to prefix all the *referenced* types. That is necessary because your *default* namespace is the XML Schema namespace. It's usually a better practice to follow the convention of using a prefix for the XML Schema namespace (usually `xs` or `xsd`) and use the target namespace as the default namespace.